# Using bash, how to assign integer to variable using echo

Tags: bash, variable-assignment

I'd like to understand bash a bit better as I'm apparently horrible at it...

I'm trying to generate a sequence of constant width integers, but then test them to do something exceptional for particular values.  Like so:

```
  for n in $(seq -w 1 150)
  do
    # The next line does not work: doit.sh: line 9: XX: command not found
    #decval= $( echo ${n} | sed 's/^0//g' | sed 's/^0//g' )
    #if [[ ${decal} -eq 98 ]] ; then
    if [[ $( echo ${n} | sed 's/^0//g' | sed 's/^0//g' ) -eq 98 ]] ; then
      echo "Do something different for 98"
    elif [[ $( echo ${n} | sed 's/^0//g' | sed 's/^0//g' ) -eq 105 ]] ; then
      echo "Do something different for 98"
    fi
  done
```

This script works for my purposes, but if I try and make the assignment 'decval= $(…' I get an error 'command not found'.   I don't understand this, can someone explain?

Also, is there an improvement I can make to this script if I have a large number of exceptions to prevent a long list of if ; then elif …  ?

Comment: It's probably easier to generate variable width, then convert to fixed width with a simple `printf`. For additional improvements, have a look at the shell's `case` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the space between `=` and `$`:

```
decval= $(…
```

You should write without spaces:

```
decval=$(...
```

Because, if you write the space, your shell reads `decval=` as `declval=""` and treats the result of `$(echo...)` as the name of a command to execute, and obviously it doesn't find the command.

Also (just a small optimization), you can write:

```
sed 's/^0\+//'
```

instead of

```
sed 's/^0//g' | sed 's/^0//g'
```

Here:

- `0\+` means `0` one or more times;
- `g` is removed, because `g` means replace all occurences in the string, and you have only one occurence (`^` can be only one time in a string).

Also, you can check your variable even with leading zeros, without `sed`:

```
[[ "$n" =~  "0*98" ]]
```

Comment: Or even `sed 's/^0*//'` which should be portable to pretty much any platform.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that… so of course I didn't try it 'again'.  D'Oh!